# Making a view "solid" in Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` positioned over the rest of my view and I want this `RelativeLayout` to stop anything underneath it from being clicked. Here is my document outline:

```
FrameLayout
    LinearLayout
    RelativeLayout
```

The `RelativeLayout` only has a background colour, and has nothing inside it. The `LinearLayout` has buttons and textboxes in it. I want to stop people from being able to click on the buttons and textboxes if the `RelativeLayout` is visible.

Comment: What if you set up an `onClicked` listener for the `RelativeLayout`? Then remove the listener when you want the buttons and textboxes selected.

Comment: You can use isClickable = false when you inflate the other layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to consume the click. Find `yourRelativeLayout` and set an `OnClickListener` on it:

```
yourRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { }
});
```

Comment: Will this stop the button from appearing clicked? (becoming darker, etc)

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

To do it in code:

```
LinearLayoutItem.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: did you set clickable property on every item?